# CSS - change position absolute left to right in IE

Tags: css

How can I override this declaration?

```
div.someClass {position:absolute; left:10px; top:20px}
```

I want this

```
div.myClass div.someClass  {position:absolute; RIGHT:10px; top:20px; left:auto;}
```

You can say, that it should work if I set **left:auto;** but it is not working in IE6,
I didn't check what happen in IE7, IE8.

How to change position using only CSS?

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the problems with CSS: How do you "unring" that bell, once a certain type of rule has been set?

Assuming your div is not in **a container that does not have its left value set already**, you could try this:

```
div#myId div.someClass {
  left: inherit;
  right: 10px;
  /* etc. */
}
```

Note that you could have saved yourself some trouble by not declaring div.someClass in the first place. The extra element in the selector is just unnecessary weight. If your selector had been .someClass you could have overridden it merely by adding div.someClass.

Answer (score 3):

You mean that you want the "myID" div to **not** obey that rule, even though it has class "someClass"?  Then you'd just put this **after** your ".someClass" rule:

```
div#myId { right: 10px; left: auto !important; }
```

(The "!important" might not be necessary; try it with and without that, and if it works without it then leave it off.)

If you mean that you want all `<div>` elements with class "someClass" that appear *inside* a `<div>` with "id" "myId", then your selector is OK but try that "!important" suffix.

Here's a sample showing that setting "left" to auto definitely works: http://gutfullofbeer.net/leftright.html

Comment: It's not "iimportant", it's "!important".

Comment: See the sample page that I linked - you must have something else wrong, because the positioning in my sample page works fine in IE6 and also in Firefox.

Comment: I updated my sample page so that it now has a "someClass" div inside a "myClass" div, and it still works fine.

Comment: you have right - its working

problem is in something else
IE just dont want to position elements with width:auto

Answer (score 0):

you can override to nothing (at least with javascript):

```
 divObject.style.left = "";
```